# How can i resolve this Artifactory issue?

Tags: artifactory

could you please help anyone I'm getting a problem with artifactory configuration  after installation successful. while access the server  error shows the below.

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 500,
    "message" : "Cannot invoke \"org.artifactory.opentracing.ArtifactoryTracer.startSpanOnCurrentThread(String, java.util.Map)\" because \"this.artifactoryTracer\" is null"
  } ]
}
```

log file:

```
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
2023-09-19T14:40:54.703Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [871943d77ab0945d] [.s.s.r.StaleTokenCleanupJob:66] [jf-access-task1     ] - Starting Access job to remove stale nodes and join-admin-tokens on server: ESTXDSRLV498

2023-09-19T15:09:26.008Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [45b4bf22f49ce7ff] [licationContextInitializer:165] [Catalina-utility-1  ] - Access (jfac) service initialization started. Version: 7.78.5 Revision: 77805900 PID: 14619 Home: /opt/jfrog/artifactory
2023-09-19T15:09:26.110Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [45b4bf22f49ce7ff] [o.j.a.AccessApplication:55    ] [Catalina-utility-1  ] - Starting AccessApplication v7.78.5 using Java 17.0.6 on ESTXDSRLV498 with PID 14619 (/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/access/WEB-INF/lib/access-application-7.78.5.jar started by artifactory in /)
2023-09-19T15:09:26.111Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [45b4bf22f49ce7ff] [o.j.a.AccessApplication:631   ] [Catalina-utility-1  ] - No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-09-19T15:09:26.170Z [jfac ] [WARN ] [45b4bf22f49ce7ff] [.c.c.ConfigDataEnvironment:258] [Catalina-utility-1  ] - Property 'spring.profiles' imported from location 'class path resource [application.yaml]' is invalid and should be replaced with 'spring.config.activate.on-profile' [origin: class path resource [application.yaml] from access-application-7.78.5.jar - 2:14]
2023-09-19T15:09:29.788Z [jfac ] [WARN ] [45b4bf22f49ce7ff] [c.z.h.u.DriverDataSource:70   ] [Catalina-utility-1  ] - Registered driver with driverClassName=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
2023-09-19T15:09:30.442Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [45b4bf22f49ce7ff] [alConfigurationServiceBase:185] [Catalina-utility-1  ] - Configuration data wasn't found in db. Loading defaults
2023-09-19T15:09:30.782Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [45b4bf22f49ce7ff] [alConfigurationServiceBase:135] [Catalina-utility-1  ] - Current configurations are the same as the new configurations, no need for an update. No action was taken.
2023-09-19T15:09:31.774Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [45b4bf22f49ce7ff] [.s.s.s.ServiceConfigFactory:44] [Catalina-utility-1  ] - Initializing task scheduler with 9 threads
2023-09-19T15:09:31.797Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [45b4bf22f49ce7ff] [j.a.s.s.t.TokenServiceImpl:172] [Catalina-utility-1  ] - Scheduling task for revoking expired tokens using cron expression: 40 25 0/1 * * ?
2023-09-19T15:09:32.243Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [45b4bf22f49ce7ff] [o.j.a.s.s.JoinKeyAccess:213   ] [Catalina-utility-1  ] - Cluster join: Join key loaded successfully (from: /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/security/join.key)
2023-09-19T15:09:32.559Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [45b4bf22f49ce7ff] [b.AccessServerBootstrapImpl:58] [Catalina-utility-1  ] - [ACCESS BOOTSTRAP] Starting JFrog Access bootstrap...
2023-09-19T15:09:32.576Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [45b4bf22f49ce7ff] [.a.s.d.s.c.v.DerbyValidator:26] [Catalina-utility-1  ] - Validating connection collation for derby database
2023-09-19T15:09:33.128Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [45b4bf22f49ce7ff] [b.AccessServerBootstrapImpl:73] [Catalina-utility-1  ] - [ACCESS BOOTSTRAP] JFrog Access bootstrap finished.
2023-09-19T15:09:33.136Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [45b4bf22f49ce7ff] [.s.j.JfConnectConfiguration:44] [Catalina-utility-1  ] - JFCON entitlements are disabled. jfconnect.enabled and jflink.enabled are false or undefined
2023-09-19T15:09:35.022Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [45b4bf22f49ce7ff] [o.j.a.s.r.s.GrpcServerImpl:80 ] [Catalina-utility-1  ] - Starting gRPC Server on port 8045
2023-09-19T15:09:35.346Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [45b4bf22f49ce7ff] [o.j.a.s.r.s.GrpcServerImpl:110] [Catalina-utility-1  ] - gRPC Server started, listening on 8045
2023-09-19T15:09:35.373Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [45b4bf22f49ce7ff] [a.c.RefreshableScheduledJob:53] [Catalina-utility-1  ] - Scheduling staleTokenCleanup task to run every 3600 seconds
2023-09-19T15:09:35.405Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [                ] [.j.a.s.s.SystemScheduledJob:37] [Catalina-utility-1  ] - Scheduling Readiness task to run with 15000 milliseconds fixed delay
2023-09-19T15:09:35.429Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [393bffa3928f80f8] [a.c.RefreshableScheduledJob:53] [Catalina-utility-1  ] - Scheduling heartbeat task to run every 5 seconds
2023-09-19T15:09:35.435Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [393bffa3928f80f8] [a.c.RefreshableScheduledJob:53] [Catalina-utility-1  ] - Scheduling KeepAliveFederationServers task to run every 86400 seconds
2023-09-19T15:09:35.441Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [393bffa3928f80f8] [a.c.RefreshableScheduledJob:53] [Catalina-utility-1  ] - Scheduling federationCleanupService task to run every 1209600 seconds
2023-09-19T15:09:35.448Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [393bffa3928f80f8] [.s.t.NotifyTokenExpiryTask:120] [Catalina-utility-1  ] - New cron schedule expression for notifying user of expiring tokens - 0 00 8 * * ?
2023-09-19T15:09:35.452Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [393bffa3928f80f8] [a.c.RefreshableScheduledJob:53] [Catalina-utility-1  ] - Scheduling EmailsLogCleanup task to run every 86400 seconds
2023-09-19T15:09:35.464Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [393bffa3928f80f8] [a.c.RefreshableScheduledJob:64] [Catalina-utility-1  ] - unusedLicensesCleanup task is disabled.
2023-09-19T15:09:35.477Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [b93415a0ed8d45ae] [a.c.RefreshableScheduledJob:53] [Catalina-utility-1  ] - Scheduling loadCertificates task to run every 30 seconds
2023-09-19T15:09:35.508Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [b93415a0ed8d45ae] [h.AccessNodeIdProviderImpl:100] [Catalina-utility-1  ] - Service id initialized: jfac@01haa4wz1h2h8k1j7yzfmz10tr, for tenant: single_tenant
2023-09-19T15:09:36.628Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [b93415a0ed8d45ae] [o.j.a.AccessApplication:61    ] [Catalina-utility-1  ] - Started AccessApplication in 11.459 seconds (JVM running for 14.9)
2023-09-19T15:09:44.761Z [jfac ] [WARN ] [b93415a0ed8d45ae] [o.j.c.ExecutionUtils:177      ] [jf-common-pool-1    ] - Retry 20 Elapsed 9.25 secs failed: Registration with router on URL http://localhost:8046 failed with error: UNAVAILABLE: io exception. Trying again
2023-09-19T15:09:49.793Z [jfac ] [WARN ] [b93415a0ed8d45ae] [o.j.c.ExecutionUtils:177      ] [jf-common-pool-1    ] - Retry 30 Elapsed 14.28 secs failed: Registration with router on URL http://localhost:8046 failed with error: UNAVAILABLE: io exception. Trying again
2023-09-19T15:09:54.831Z [jfac ] [WARN ] [b93415a0ed8d45ae] [o.j.c.ExecutionUtils:177      ] [jf-common-pool-1    ] - Retry 40 Elapsed 19.32 secs failed: Registration with router on URL http://localhost:8046 failed with error: UNAVAILABLE: io exception. Trying again
2023-09-19T15:09:59.844Z [jfac ] [WARN ] [b93415a0ed8d45ae] [o.j.c.ExecutionUtils:177      ] [jf-common-pool-1    ] - Retry 50 Elapsed 24.33 secs failed: Registration with router on URL http://localhost:8046 failed with error: UNAVAILABLE: io exception. Trying again
2023-09-19T15:10:04.856Z [jfac ] [WARN ] [b93415a0ed8d45ae] [o.j.c.ExecutionUtils:177      ] [jf-common-pool-1    ] - Retry 60 Elapsed 29.35 secs failed: Registration with router on URL http://localhost:8046 failed with error: UNAVAILABLE: io exception. Trying again
2023-09-19T15:10:09.868Z [jfac ] [WARN ] [b93415a0ed8d45ae] [o.j.c.ExecutionUtils:177      ] [jf-common-pool-1    ] - Retry 70 Elapsed 34.36 secs failed: Registration with router on URL http://localhost:8046 failed with error: UNAVAILABLE: io exception. Trying again
2023-09-19T15:10:14.880Z [jfac ] [WARN ] [b93415a0ed8d45ae] [o.j.c.ExecutionUtils:177      ] [jf-common-pool-1    ] - Retry 80 Elapsed 39.37 secs failed: Registration with router on URL http://localhost:8046 failed with error: UNAVAILABLE: io exception. Trying again
```

please let me know the solution Thanks.

Comment: Not enough information. OS ? Installer type (rpm/archive/docker...) ? What in the router log ?

Comment: You don't give errors correctly, add more important about your problem not add all of logs.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same issue in a slightly different context.

try this:

```
cd  /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/etc
touch artifactory.lic
chown 1030:1030 artifactory.lic
chmod 640 artifactory.lic
```

create (or update) system.yaml (will be in etc/ folder)

```
shared:
  node:
    ip: 0.0.0.0
```

https://jfrog.com/help/r/access-router-connectivity-node-ip/getting-access-service/router-connectivity-issues-on-startup-try-setting-the-node-ip

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried with that solution but not working.

Answer (score 0):

Check `console.log` for AF. I've encountered this problem while setup JRC with error `Error starting application - Error: Failed pinging artifactory for 300connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8046` it seems that port related to `router` was filtered. For me it was SElinux. Maybe you have the same issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).